# Rings, ideals and quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $I$ is an ideal of ring $R$, and $J'$ is an ideal of $R/I$. Show there is an ideal $J$ in $R$ so that $J/I=J'$.

How do I answer this? What am I required to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a canonical map $\varphi : R \to R/I$. You want an ideal $J$ in $R$ so that $\varphi(J)=J'$. You answer this by finding the ideal and proving it satisfies that condition.

Comment: What @jgon means is: try $J=\varphi ^{-1} (J')$.

Comment: @Alex M. Indeed, but I thought I'd let the OP figure that part out.